# Primefaces extensions CK editor always rendered as textarea

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, ckeditor, primefaces-extensions

I am using pe:ckEditor in one of my pages but they are always rendered as text area. My code below.

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="#{resource['jquery.js']}" />
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces-extensions"
        name="#{resource['primefaces-extensions.js']}" />
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces"
        name="#{resource['primefaces.js']}" />
</h:head>


<pe:ckEditor id="#{peId}" value="Sample"
    toolbar="[['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-', 'SpellChecker'], '/', ['Undo', 'Redo']]"
    skin="office2013">
</pe:ckEditor>
```

I have the resources ck editor jar also added in my pom file along with primefaces extensions

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
  <version>6.2.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your CKEditor import to match the version of extensions like this...

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
  <version>6.2.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
  <artifactId>resources-ckeditor</artifactId>
  <version>6.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

That will fix your issue. Those version must always match.